# Pandas: Adding row by row while iterating a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large dictionaries that has list has values. For this question purpose I name them as dictionary foo and bar.

```
foo = {}
foo['a'] = []
foo['b'] = []
foo['a'].append(1)
foo['a'].append(2)
foo['b'].append(10)
foo['b'].append(30)

bar = {}
bar['a'] = []
bar['a'].append(5)
bar['a'].append(7)
bar['b'] = []
bar['b'].append(8)
bar['b'].append(34)
bar['b'].append(32)
```

By iterating one dictionary I want to construct a data frame which will get me following data table:

```
id | viewed | presented
-----------------------
a  | [1,2]  | [5,7]
-----------------------
b  | [10,30]| [8,32,34]
```

So I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'viewed', 'presented'])
for item in foo:
    df = pd.Series({'id':item, 'viewed':foo[item], 'presented':bar[item]})
```

but when I print my data frame it was missing results of `foo[a]` and `bar[a]`

```
>>> df
id                     b
presented    [8, 34, 32]
viewed          [10, 30]
dtype: object
>>> len(df.index)
3
```

Looks like it getting over written instead of increasing the index of the data frame to record the next element. What is the best way to solve this issue and insert row wise as I needed in this case. I looked at two other stackoverflow questions both didn't have the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'viewed':foo, 'presented':bar}).reset_index()
df.columns = ['id', 'viewed', 'presented']
```

And you will get the desired data frame of:

```
   id    viewed    presented
0  a    [1, 2]       [5, 7]
1  b  [10, 30]  [8, 34, 32]
```

Comment: this way id will be the index of the data frame right? which I don't want. I want that to be a column.

Comment: just to be clear I don't need to iterate over dictionary? as I was doing in the question?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis No you don't need to since you already constructed the data as a dictionary and `Pandas.DataFrame` can infer that you mean to build from that dictionary. Pandas also has a `Pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(...)` functionality that you can check out in the docs -->http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html